# How to run docker builds from Jenkins on a Mac?

Tags: macos, jenkins, docker

How can I from my locally installed Jenkins run a `docker build` on my Mac? Normally when I run `docker build` I need to do it from the `Docker Quickstart Terminal` but now I want to have Jenkins make the docker call. Clearly simply running `docker build...` as an "Execute shell" component in Jenkins...

Must I run a separate Docker image with Jenkins which runs the `docker build` command?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jenkins's plugin that help you to manage integration with Docker.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

I wrote this blogpost, maybe it's a little big over your question but I hope to be helpful
http://gianarb.it/blog/docker-inside-docker-and-jenkins-2

The idea could be, just to start, install docker into the same Jenkins's server and build your project directly with a shell command, push this image inside a registry and you can use:

```
docker pull registry:username/imagename
```

to update your local image.. it's not a good practice build from Jenkins on your local machine.
The concept is:
Jenkins build and push your image and you will update that in your local/dev/prod environment.

Comment: Hm, the point is that my build server is really slow and since I am just messing myself now I want to run it locally until I get it working. The build server is fine later on for nightly builds. The problem with "install docker into the same Jenkins's server and build your project directly with a shell command" is that shell command can't really work on the Mac now can it? At least it seems to need a special shell, the so called `Docker Quickstart Terminal`